# How to know if the user is logged as a seller in my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I just started to code in ruby, so it's a beginner's doubt. I'm working in a market place application. I'm trying to create in my seller's show a condition depending if the user is a seller, but it's not working.

I have this configuration in my models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :sellers
  has_many :products, through: :sellers
  has_many :orders
  has_many :reviews

end
```

```
class Seller < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :orders
  has_many :reviews, through: :orders
  has_many :products
end
```

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :seller
end
```

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :seller
  has_many :reviews
end
```

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :order
end
```

It's my Sellers Controller:

```
class SellersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @sellers = Seller.all
  end

  def show
    @seller = Seller.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = current_user
    @seller = Seller.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @seller = Seller.new(seller_params)
    @seller.user = @user
    if @seller.save
      redirect_to seller_path(@seller.id), notice: 'Sua loja foi criada com sucesso!'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end


  def edit
  end


  private

  def seller_params
    params.require(:seller).permit(:seller_name, :category)
  end

end
```

Bellow, my Products Controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @seller = current_user.seller
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
      redirect_to product_path(@product.id), notice: 'Novo produto criado com sucesso!'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:product_name, :product_description, :product_size, :product_price)
  end

end
```

I'm trying to code the seller's show like this, but it's not working:

```
<h1>Seller details</h1>

<h3> <%= @seller.seller_name %> </h3>
<p> <%= @seller.category %> </p>
<% if current_user.seller %>
  <%= link_to "Create new product", new_product_path(@product), class: 'btn btn-primary' %> %>
<% else %>
  <%= @products.each do |product| %>
    <h4> <%= product.product_name %> </h4>
    <p> <%= product.product_description %> </p>
    <p> <%= product.product_size %> </p>
    <h6> <%= product.product_price %> </h6>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I apply this condition if the user is a seller? Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a User has one seller you should set as this:

```
   class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_one :seller
    end
```

Comment: doing that, the same error persists: undefined method `seller' for #<User:0x00007efcac258a28>

Comment: I overlooked how you set the association. See updated answer